# Trying to add Caroufredsel Slider Pagination bullets

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Caroufredsel slider and I want to have two pagination bullets at the bottom. There are 6 items in my slider and the slider usually shows 4 items and then slides one by one. I want the slider to slide that way but also I want the pagination bullets to show 4 items at the first bullet and 2 items directly at the second bullet after they are clicked.

Moreover, I am getting numbers. How can I change them to bullets? Anyone here who can help?

My Code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  // portfolio slider

  $('.team-carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive: true,
    width: '100%;',
    circular: true,
    pagination: {
      container: "#pagination",
      anchorBuilder: true
    },
    scroll: {
      items: 1,
      fx: 'crossfade',
      duration: 400,
      pauseOnHover: true
    },
    auto: true,
    items: {
      visible: {
        min: 1,
        max: 4
      },
      height: "variable"
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.2.1/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js"></script>

<div class="carousel text-center">
    <ul class="team-carousel">
        <li>
            <div class="inner-content text-center">
                <img src="img/person3.jpg">
                <h2>Jason Statham</h2>
                <h3>Knife Designer</h3>
                <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="inner-content text-center">
                <img src="img/person1.jpg">
                <h2>Van Damme</h2>
                <h3>No English</h3>
                <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="inner-content text-center">
                <img src="img/person4.jpg">
                <h2>Sylverter Stallone</h2>
                <h3>Cigar Lover</h3>
                <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="inner-content text-center">
                <img src="img/person2.jpg">
                <h2>Jet Li</h2>
                <h3>I need more money</h3>
                <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="inner-content text-center">
                <img src="img/person1.jpg">
                <h2>A Zaker</h2>
                <h3>Monster Killer</h3>
                <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="inner-content text-center">
                <img src="img/person2.jpg">
                <h2>Zaker Olive</h2>
                <h3>Soul Crusher</h3>
                <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="pagination" class="pager"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This carousel seems outdated. The doc is inexistant. Maybe you should use another one like [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: oh wow. Slick is so slick. lol. The codes are so simple. Thank you. I think I'll migrate to it.